# Limit without l'Hospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

need help with this limit without l'Hospital

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty }\frac{\arctan\left(-\frac{4}{x}\right)}{\left|\arctan\frac{3}{x}\right|}$$

Comment: Your $\infty$ is $+\infty$ or unsigned $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$f(x)\to 0\implies\frac{\arctan(f(x))}{f(x)}\to 1.$$
Also important: the sign of $\arctan\frac{3}{x}$.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{\arctan(-\frac{4}{x})}{\left|\arctan\frac{3}{x}\right|}=
\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{-\arctan(\frac{4}{x})\frac{4}{x}}{\left|\arctan\frac{3}{x}\right|\frac{4}{x}}
\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{-\arctan(\frac{4}{x})}{\frac{4}{x}}\frac{\frac{4}{x}}{\left|\arctan\frac{3}{x}\right|}=\cdots
$$

Comment: can you write me procedure? I am noob with this...

Comment: How do you derive the 'hint' without L'Hospital?

Comment: @daw, see the geometric proof of $\sin x/x\to 1$ when $x\to 0$ in  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X.

Answer (score 0):

Using "$\arctan x \sim x$ as $x\to 0$"

So $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\arctan \frac{-4}{x}}{|\arctan \frac3x|} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{-4}{x}}{| \frac3x|} =  \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-4}{3}\cdot\frac{|x|}{x}$$

As $x\to +\infty$, it is 1; and As $x\to -\infty$, it is -1. So its limit does not exist!

Comment: $\infty$ *can* be interpreted as $+\infty$. And I've corrected your typo.

Comment: Why? $\infty$ does not equal $+\infty$.

Comment: Sometimes unsigned $\infty$ isn't defined to students.

Answer (score 0):

Almost completely without calculus: The $|\cdot|$  in the denominator is irrelevant.
We are interested in $\frac\alpha\beta$ where $\tan\alpha=-\frac4x$ and $\tan\beta=\frac3x$ with $x\gg0$ (i.e. $\frac3x$ and $-\frac4x$ are small). For small angles we know from the addition theorems for $\tan$ that $\tan(\pm kx)\approx\pm k\tan x$, hence $\alpha\approx -4\gamma$ and $\beta\approx 3\gamma$ for $\gamma$ with $\tan \gamma=\frac1x$. Conclusion: $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\approx -\frac43$.

Comment: The absvalue is irrelevant *if* $\infty$ is $+\infty$.